# Suppose that $G$ is a group and $N\unlhd G$ a normal subgroup. Prove $G/N$ is simple

Tags: group-theory

> Suppose that $G$ is a group and $N\unlhd G$ a normal subgroup. Assume that there is no
> normal subgroup $M\unlhd G$ with $N\le M$. Prove that $G/N$ is simple.

This problem is really throwing me for a loop. The concept of quotient groups and how they relate to simple subgroups is confusing me, and so I am not really sure how to begin. If a simple subgroup's only normal subgroup is itself (and the trivial group), then $G/N$ being simple would be proving that when multiplying the entire subgroup $N$ by an element $g$ for all $g$ in $G$, that the collection of those sets cannot be broken into smaller normal subgroups?

Comment: In other words, if $f:G\to H$ is a surjective homomorphism with kernel $N$, and if $H$ is not simple (and not trivial), you want to show that $G$ has a normal subgroup between $N$ and $G$. **Hint:** Consider a nontrivial normal subgroup of $H$ . . .

Comment: Is thee a typo in the question? Did you mean to write: "Assume that there is no normal subgroup $M\unlhd G$ with $N\le M$ **except** $M=N$ and $M=G$"?

Answer (score 0):

Try to show that there is a correspondence between subgroups of $G/N$ and subgroups of $G$ containing $N$. Also show that this correspondence preserves notions of normality.

[In fact, you have hinted at this correspondence in your question: a subgroup $\{ g_1N, \dots , g_k N\}$ of $G/N$ corresponds to the subgroup $g_1N \cup \dots \cup g_k N$ of $G$, which clearly contains $N$.]

Comment: I can see how the correspondence exists fairly easily I think. Does it preserve normality because the definition of normality says that any gN and therefore Ng is in N because normality says that for all g in g and all n in N that this is true?

Comment: Suppose $N \unlhd H \unlhd G$. The fact that $H$ is normal in $G$ is the same as saying that $gHg^{-1} = H$ for any $g \in G$. Try to show that this implies a similar normality condition for $H/N$ in $G/N$.

Comment: So H/N being normal in G/N would mean (gn)(nH)(gn)^(-1) = H/N?  I guess I am a little stuck on how they relate

Answer (score 0):

"I am not really sure how to begin":

If $M$ is a normal subgroup and $N<M$ prove the following:

- $N$ is a normal subgroup of $M$.
- $M/N$ is a normal subgroup of $G/N$.